# Set last 3 bits of size_t

Tags: c, bit

Lets say I have two variable of type size_t

```
size_t number;
size_t realNumber = (any value here);
```

And I want to set the least 3 significant bits to this enum

```
typedef enum three {
    lastThree = 0b001,
} three;
```

I've been doing this but it doesn't seem to be working

```
number = realNumber | lastThree;
```

Can someone help me? I need the number to be the realNumber, and the last 3 significant digits to be the lastThree enum.

Comment: No in my problem its define as 0b001

Comment: `or will do just that—it won’t *clear* bits 1/2, only bit 0 is guaranteed to be what you want (1). If you want to clear the bits then you should clear them.

Comment: If the `enum` is defined as having only one value, setting the last three bits of anything to that value is useless - you've added no information if the last three bits are always the same. And if they're not always the same bits as the one value you've supplied as a possible enumeration value, those bits do not represent that `enum`.  Right now, this quetion doesn't make any sense.  Have you left something significant out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first clear the last three bits for any residuals.

```
size_t number;
const size_t last3bitClearFlag = ~(size_t)0b111;
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
size_t realNumber = (any value here);
number = (realNumber & last3bitClearFlag) | lastThree;
//       ^           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Demystifying `last3bitClearFlag` (from comments)

```
 ([..] for skipping long series of same bits)
 0b111 is 0[..]0111
~0b111 is 1[..]1000 (flipped)
Number & (~0b111) = all bits preserved except last 3 are replaced with zeroes
```

Comment: what does the ~0x7 stand for? 7 digit spaces?

Comment: `0×7` is 7 in hexadecimal (and decimal) or `0b111` in binary: the last 3 bit are on. `~` is a binary operand that reverse bits: every bits except the last 3 are on. Note that the `0b` format is not standard.